# Swift Core Data - Insert multiple data in two entities related

Tags: swift, insert, relationship

I'm trying to insert data in three different entities using two for loops. These entities are related but only the first record is getting the relationship.

I create the Marca record OK, but when i'm creating Cerveja, only the first one gets the relationship with Marca.

```
        let entityMarca = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Marca", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        let entityProduto = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Produto", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        let entityCerveja = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Cerveja", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        for novaMarca in Marcas{
            let marca = Marca(entity: entityMarca!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
            marca.nome = novaMarca
            marca.original = BoolCoreData.verdadeiro

            for novoProduto in Produtos{
                let produto = Produto(entity: entityProduto!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
                produto.nome = novoProduto
                produto.original = BoolCoreData.verdadeiro
                        let cerveja = Cerveja(entity: entityCerveja!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
                        cerveja.marca = marca
                        cerveja.produto = produto
                        cerveja.imagem = "\(marca.nome) \(produto.nome)"
                        cerveja.volume = 269
                        cerveja.comparar = BoolCoreData.verdadeiro
            }
        }
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error!!")
        }
```

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

Updating with data model:

[image: First Entity]

[image: Second Entity]

Comment: Are you sure that you `xcdatamodeld` file is well defined?

Comment: I think so, i'll update my question with some screens...